# How to download packages in Pycharm using anaconda as it's interpreter?

Tags: python, package, pycharm, anaconda

I have a problem. I am running python 3.10 and Anaconda 3.9 on the same machine. When I use Anaconda 3.9 as my interpreter in Pycharm, and download a package, it will install the package on python 3.10

If put in the terminal `pip install pygame`, it will tell me requirement already satisfied.
But when I try to import pygame it will say `no module named 'pygame'`.

NOTE: The problem occurs ONLY with anaconda as my interpreter, not with python 3.10 as my interpreter.

How do I specify on what version I want the package downloaded on ?
And with which command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that Anaconda 3.9 interpreter is not activated in the terminal you're using to install module. Therefore, while executing the command `pip install pygame` in the terminal, falls back to use the default python interpreter set to your device which is Python 3.10.

Viable Solutions:

1. Use of virtual environments, which activate by default if exist in the project root folder. (recommended and best practice)
2. Install module through [PyCharm Available Packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/available-packages.html).
3. Use the Anaconda Prompt.
4. Use the Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: Hey, so I tried using the Anaconda Command Prompt and it works like a charm, thanks ! Note: I also tried using the Anaconda navigator which worked too.